# Rspec selecting wrong table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get RSpec up and running on my new mountable engine gem. I've followed the guides for setting up rspec on a mountable engine. I'm falling short when I'm setting up fixtures. it's not namespacing the tablename _clips so i'm getting a sql error. I know there's some problems with this and was wondering if there was a good solution.

THanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be fixed by https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/448 (fixed in git, but not yet released). Try pointing your Gemfile to rspec-rails from github and see if does:

```
gem "rspec-rails", :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git"
```

Comment: thanks for that, i figured it out last night but didn't have the chance to update the answer.